# What is the best practice of writing an asynchronous safe singleton?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, locking

I am trying to have some sort of singleton/semaphore mechanisms that will be "async-safe".

My goal is to have only one instance of an IPFS `node` is being created in the entire lifetime of my node.js app.

At the moment what I am doing is the following which is absolutely unsafe for some cases.

```
const IPFS = import('ipfs-core');

const getIPFSNode = async () => {
  if (module.exports.ipfsNode === undefined) {
    ipfs = await IPFS;
    const node = await ipfs.create();
    module.exports.ipfsNode = node;
  }
  return module.exports.ipfsNode;
};
```

How could I assure only one instance of IFPS node is being created? Is there a way to create the creation an atomic operation or protect it with a semaphore/mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work, although it has a kind of unexpected side effect of yielding on every call, even once the promise is settled.

```
const IPFS = import('ipfs-core');

let promise;
const getIPFSNode = () => {
  if (promise === undefined) {
    promise = IPFS.create();
  }
  return promise;
};
```